# Get-SPExcelServiceApplication Cmdlet not recognized during Powerpivot configuration

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, excel-services, powerpivot

I am trying to run the sharepoint powerpivot configuration tool however I am getting a message saying:

> The term 'Get-SPExcelServiceApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again.

I have tried running the command in the Sharepoint 2010 management shell and get the same problem. I have read that this may be related to my license type and according to central admin my license is "SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License".

In central admin I have also done the following:

-Central Admin -> Operations -> Upgrade and Migration -> Enable Enterprise Features

-Central Admin -> Operations -> Upgrade and Migration -> Enable Enterprise Features on Existing Sites

Any other suggestions on how I can get this cmdlet to be recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be related to not **ALL** of the excel service application features being enabled in sharepoint. In order to activate the features go to central admin and then:

```
/_admin/ManageFarmFeatures.aspx
```

From here you can enable the following features:

Excel Services Application Edit Farm Feature

Excel Services Application View Farm Feature

Excel Services Application Web Part Farm Feature